# Best strategy for too many Elements in FireMoneky TListView Item

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe8

Believe me I did my homework before reaching out for help. I spent last 3 days searching and reading but I couldn't come to a solution. So any help will be highly appreciated.

My task is to have a ListView connected to a Dataset where the ListView Item is of the following structure:
[image]

Bear in mind that

1. Elements 4, 6, & 8 are of fixed values & Color (i.e. labels)
2. Colors of Elements 1 & 10 depends on values of Elements 5, 7, & 9

Best what I got is references to Delphi Standard Example that shifts with Embarcadero Delphi Examples directory: ListViewMultiDetailAppearance.
This solution offers to create our own class for MutliDetailItemAppearance and register as many details as we need (in my case I need additional 8 I think).

Now my questions:

1. Is this the best approach?
2. if not, what is the better approach?
3. if it is, how adding additional 8 details will affect the
   performance?
4. and most important how to reach custom coloring for elements for
   each List View Item based on the values?
5. and finally how to reach this sections borders? and List item bottom
   borders (the green line)?

Thank you very much for your thoughts in advance.

Comment: Number 4 would be subject to another question, and I'm not sure what you mean in number 5. But I'm sure 4 could be figured out easily in the code I provided.

Comment: @JerryDodge in the picture you see the vertical lines between 3 sections. and the bottom green line to the whole list view item.
as for number 4, any ideas?

Comment: A `TListItemText` can be customized to match whatever font styling you wish, and for the lines, you may inherit your own class from `TListItemObject` and do the drawing as needed.

Comment: @JerryDodge Seems to me that your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339179/create-a-customized-item-appearance-for-listview-delphi-xe7/31504499#31504499 answer IS THE answer.
now If you can only elaborate on what other objects could be used beside TListItemText and if you can also elaborate on your comment above about inheriting TListItemObject to do the drawing as needed.
Finally, if we are talking about linking to DataSet, what do you think the best place to catch the population of DataSet values to list items so we can assign the right values to the right objects?

Comment: @JerryDodge One more issue, how do you suggest to close this question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87022/discussion-between-oussama-al-rifai-and-jerry-dodge).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that my way was correct, but I was using TListbox for alike purpose in my fmx project. The structure of its items was formed in the following way during filling from `DataSource` by `LiveBindings`.

```
procedure THMICD10Fr.LinkListControlToField1FillingListItem(Sender: TObject;
  const AEditor: IBindListEditorItem);
begin
  if (Assigned(AEditor)) and (HDM2.FDQicd_detail_for_TreeView.Active) then
    try
      if (AEditor.CurrentObject as TMetropolisUIListBoxItem).ChildrenCount = 2
      then
      begin

        with TPanel.Create(AEditor.CurrentObject as TMetropolisUIListBoxItem) do
        begin
          Parent := (AEditor.CurrentObject as TMetropolisUIListBoxItem);
          Align := TAlignLayout.alRight;
          Width := 45;
          Margins.Bottom := 1;
          Margins.Top := 1;
        end;

        with TLabel.Create((AEditor.CurrentObject as TMetropolisUIListBoxItem)
          .Children.Items[2] as TPanel) do
        begin
          Parent := (AEditor.CurrentObject as TMetropolisUIListBoxItem)
            .Children.Items[2] as TPanel;
          Text := '↓';
          VertTextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
          TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
          Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
          HitTest := true;
          AutoSize := false;
          StyledSettings := StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.ssStyle];
          Font.Style := Font.Style + [TFontStyle.fsBold];
          Tag := HDM2.FDQicd_detail_for_TreeView.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
          TagString := HDM2.FDQicd_detail_for_TreeView.FieldByName
            ('category_etiology').AsString;
          OnClick := LabelInListBox1Click;
        end;
      end;

    except

    end;
end;
```

This code gave me the following appearence:
[image]

You can create and nest all necessary `TLayouts`, `TLabels` etc. inside the Item and set all the necessary settings using the logics from inside the `LiveBindings` event handler.

Comment: Thanks @asd-tm 
Unfortunately, using of TListBox is not an options for performance reasons.
It would be the perfect approach, I guess, if I can use TListBox in my app but I really need a solution related to TListView.

Comment: Thank you, but can't you do the same with `TListView` Items while handling OnFillingListItemEvent as it relates not to the type of container but to `LiveBindings` mechanism?

Comment: I guess not. as TListView item doesn't accept children controls. does it?

Comment: @OussamaAlRifai You can make your own drawn elements in a `TListView`. Not necessarily any control though. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339179/create-a-customized-item-appearance-for-listview-delphi-xe7/31504499#31504499

Comment: @JerryDodge. Can you elaborate on your comment?
It would be the best if you are sure to answer the question (instead of comment) in order to discuss and if it woks, I will set your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @OussamaAlRifai My answer on that other question I linked does exactly what you need. If that solves your question, then yours should rather be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JerryDodge I am exploring your link now. I will get back to you.