# Firemonkey: Add child control to TListViewItem at run time

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I am attempting to add a `TEdit` control to a `TListView` control during run time.  I want to parent the `TEdit` control to the selected `TListViewItem` belonging to my `TListView`, however, I cannot find a way to do this.

Originally, I tried this:

```
TEdit * MyEdit = new TEdit( this );
MyEdit->Parent = MyListView->Selected;
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> [bcc32 Error] E2034 Cannot convert 'TListViewItem *' to 'TFmxObject *'

On a whim, I attempted to typecast the selected item on my list view as a `TFmxObject` like so:

```
MyEdit->Parent = (TFmxObject *)MyListView->Selected;
```

While this compiled, this caused an access violation at run time.

I have searched through a lot of documentation and forum posts and cannot find very much information about dynamically adding a control to a list view item in code.  I have seen solutions which propose using the style editor, but I want to avoid that if at all possible.

How can I set the parent of a control to an item in my `TListView`?  Is there a better / more proper way to add controls to a `TListViewItem` during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Embarcadero [documentation,](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewItem) `TListViewItem` is not a `TFmxObject` descendant and thus it can not be set as a `Parent` to the desired `TEdit` instance. It does not have `Children` property as well. Nor do the `TextObject`, `DetailObject` etc. (the `TListItemObject` descendants contained in `TListViewItem`) [ascend from](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.Types.TListItemObject) `TFmxObject`.
It seems you have the following ways out.

1. Write and register another `ListViewItem` class and implement it inside your `ListView`s or
2. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32008550/5043424) and [this SO links.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29339179/5043424) Probably, they might be useful.
3. Consider using `TListBox` instead. `TListBoxItem`s can parent other controls.

Comment: I think suggestion number 3 is the moral of the story here.  The `TListBox` looks to be the more appropriate control to use to accomplish my goals.  Thanks!