# Add TSwitch to every TListView item

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, tlistview

I haven't attempted this because I wouldn't know where to begin.

Is it possible to add a FMX TSwitch into a FMX TListViewitem?

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I have tried to do this, I and can't see any easy way to do it at design time.      Maybe there is a runtime option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first have to keep in mind the whole design of the `TListView` control. It's meant to be very lightweight for when it contains a large number of items. You may have a million items, you surely don't want a million switch controls instantiated. Therefore, it's not meant for you to embed controls in each item as a container, such as the `TListBox` allows.

That being said, it's assumed that you perform minimal drawing on each individual list item to be consistent with the design of the `TListView`. This requires creating virtual objects inherited from `TListItemObject` to be associated with each item. These objects are what allow the existing built-in elements of any item, such as the accessory or bitmap.

Here's a **very rough** demo I threw together to get you started, you'd need to change the drawing how you need it to look.

Start a new FMX application, drop a `TListView`, and use this unit in place of your main form's unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type

  TListItemSwitch = class(TListItemSimpleControl)
  private
    FIsChecked: Boolean;
    FOnSwitch: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetIsChecked(const AValue: Boolean);
  protected
    function MouseDown(const Button: TMouseButton; const Shift: TShiftState; const MousePos: TPointF): Boolean;
      override;
    procedure DoSwitch; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(const AOwner: TListItem); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Render(const Canvas: TCanvas; const DrawItemIndex: Integer; const DrawStates: TListItemDrawStates;
      const SubPassNo: Integer = 0); override;

  public
    property IsChecked: Boolean read FIsChecked write SetIsChecked;
    property OnSwitch: TNotifyEvent read FOnSwitch write FOnSwitch;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
      const AItem: TListViewItem);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TListItemSwitch }

constructor TListItemSwitch.Create(const AOwner: TListItem);
begin
  inherited;

end;

destructor TListItemSwitch.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.DoSwitch;
begin
  FIsChecked:= not FIsChecked;
  if Assigned(OnSwitch) then
    OnSwitch(Self);
end;

function TListItemSwitch.MouseDown(const Button: TMouseButton;
  const Shift: TShiftState; const MousePos: TPointF): Boolean;
begin
  if (Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft) and Enabled then begin
    DoSwitch;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.Render(const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const DrawItemIndex: Integer; const DrawStates: TListItemDrawStates;
  const SubPassNo: Integer);
var
  R, R2: TRectF;
begin
  inherited;

  R:= Self.LocalRect;
  R2:= R;

  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try

    Canvas.Stroke.Kind:= TBrushKind.None;
    Canvas.Fill.Kind:= TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Skyblue;
    Canvas.FillRect(R, 8, 8,
      [TCorner.TopLeft, TCorner.TopRight, TCorner.BottomLeft, TCorner.BottomRight],
      1.0, TCornerType.Round);

    if IsChecked then begin
      R2.Left:= R.Right - 20;
      R2.Width:= 20;
    end else begin
      R2.Left:= R.Left;
      R2.Width:= 20;
    end;

    Canvas.Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Canvas.FillRect(R2, 8, 8,
      [TCorner.TopLeft, TCorner.TopRight, TCorner.BottomLeft, TCorner.BottomRight],
      1.0, TCornerType.Round);

  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetIsChecked(const AValue: Boolean);
begin
  FIsChecked:= AValue;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: TListViewItem;
begin
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;

end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  S: TListItemSwitch;
begin
  S:= AItem.Objects.FindObject('Switch') as TListItemSwitch;
  if S = nil then begin
    S:= TListItemSwitch.Create(AItem);
    S.Name:= 'Switch';
    S.Align:= TListItemAlign.Trailing;
    S.VertAlign:= TListItemAlign.Center;
    S.Width:= 50;
    S.Height:= 20;
    S.IsChecked:= False;
  end;

end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot]

NOTE: This was written in Delphi 10 Seattle.

Your only other options I believe are to either:

1. Instantiate a `TSwitch` for each item and render it using the same method as above (Very sloppy, I do not recommend)
2. Figure out how to implement the drawing of the standard `TSwitch` using styles, again using the same method as above (which is probably the best option for performance and visual adaption)
3. Resort to a `TListBox` instead, depending on how you intend to use the list (which would be very heavy on a large number of items)

I went a little more in-depth about the differences between a `TListView` and a `TListBox` in Firemonkey in [a separate question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504499/988445).

Comment: On the plus side, this is a lot more efficient than the standard one - less drawing, no animations, and reliable to the click (because the `TSwitch` has some strange glitches). However, there's another glitch where merely selecting a line will toggle the switch.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jerry , exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @6String_Coder Here's a good implementation of it without the complexity I've already added on top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083809/click-events-being-caught-by-list-view-parent-item Long story short, I'm creating a list view controller component which allows you to "design" the list view items in a design-time component editor.

Comment: @6String_Coder Or here's a more established version: http://pastebin.com/U47Bnibn ... I'm using it currently to build a much larger library.