# Click events being caught by list view parent item

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm writing a custom switch object to be used in Firemonkey's `TListView` control per item. Everything works as expected, except for one strange glitch. When the user clicks on one of the items, but not on the particular switch object, it toggles the switch anyway. I'm assuming the `MouseDown` event is triggered when the user clicks on the list item, and not necessarily my particular "control" drawn on it.

How do I restrict the click event to only apply when the user clicks the actual switch?

**JD.ListViewObjects.pas**

```
unit JD.ListViewObjects;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.ListView;

type
  TLISwitchThumbStyle = (tsRect, tsRoundRect, tsElipse);

  TListItemSwitch = class(TListItemSimpleControl)
  private
    FIsChecked: Boolean;
    FOnSwitch: TNotifyEvent;
    FThumbStyle: TLISwitchThumbStyle;
    FThumbWidth: Single;
    FThumbHeight: Single;
    FThumbRound: Single;
    procedure SetIsChecked(const AValue: Boolean);
    procedure SetThumbStyle(const Value: TLISwitchThumbStyle);
    procedure SetThumbWidth(const Value: Single);
    procedure SetThumbHeight(const Value: Single);
    procedure SetThumbRound(const Value: Single);
  protected
    function MouseDown(const Button: TMouseButton; const Shift: TShiftState; const MousePos: TPointF): Boolean;
      override;
    procedure DoSwitch; virtual;
    procedure Render(const Canvas: TCanvas; const DrawItemIndex: Integer; const DrawStates: TListItemDrawStates;
      const SubPassNo: Integer = 0); override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AOwner: TListItem); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  public
    property IsChecked: Boolean read FIsChecked write SetIsChecked;
    property ThumbWidth: Single read FThumbWidth write SetThumbWidth;
    property ThumbHeight: Single read FThumbHeight write SetThumbHeight;
    property ThumbStyle: TLISwitchThumbStyle read FThumbStyle write SetThumbStyle;
    property ThumbRound: Single read FThumbRound write SetThumbRound;
    property OnSwitch: TNotifyEvent read FOnSwitch write FOnSwitch;
  end;

implementation

{ TListItemSwitch }

constructor TListItemSwitch.Create(const AOwner: TListItem);
begin
  inherited;
  Width:= 50;
  Height:= 20;
  FIsChecked:= False;
  FThumbWidth:= 15;
  FThumbHeight:= 15;
  FThumbRound:= 3;
end;

destructor TListItemSwitch.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

function TListItemSwitch.MouseDown(const Button: TMouseButton;
  const Shift: TShiftState; const MousePos: TPointF): Boolean;
begin
  if (Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft) and Enabled then begin
    DoSwitch;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.DoSwitch;
begin
  FIsChecked:= not FIsChecked;
  if Assigned(OnSwitch) then
    OnSwitch(Self);
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetIsChecked(const AValue: Boolean);
begin
  FIsChecked:= AValue;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetThumbWidth(const Value: Single);
begin
  FThumbWidth := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetThumbHeight(const Value: Single);
begin
  FThumbHeight := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetThumbRound(const Value: Single);
begin
  FThumbRound := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.SetThumbStyle(const Value: TLISwitchThumbStyle);
begin
  FThumbStyle := Value;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TListItemSwitch.Render(const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const DrawItemIndex: Integer; const DrawStates: TListItemDrawStates;
  const SubPassNo: Integer);
var
  R, R2: TRectF;
  D: Single;
begin
  inherited;
  R:= Self.LocalRect;
  R2:= R;
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Canvas.Stroke.Kind:= TBrushKind.None;
    Canvas.Fill.Kind:= TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Skyblue;
    Canvas.FillRect(R, FThumbRound, FThumbRound,
      [TCorner.TopLeft, TCorner.TopRight, TCorner.BottomLeft, TCorner.BottomRight],
      1.0, TCornerType.Round);
    R2.Top:= R.Top + (R.Height / 2) - (FThumbHeight / 2);
    R2.Height:= FThumbHeight;
    D:= R2.Top - R.Top;
    if IsChecked then begin
      R2.Left:= R.Right - FThumbWidth - D;
    end else begin
      R2.Left:= R.Left + D;
    end;
    R2.Width:= FThumbWidth;
    Canvas.Fill.Color:= TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Canvas.FillRect(R2, FThumbRound, FThumbRound,
      [TCorner.TopLeft, TCorner.TopRight, TCorner.BottomLeft, TCorner.BottomRight],
      1.0, TCornerType.Round);
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
end.
```

**uListViewSwitchTest.pas**

```
unit uListViewSwitchTest;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls,
  JD.ListViewObjects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
      const AItem: TListViewItem);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;
  function A: TListViewItem;
  begin
    Result:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  end;
begin
  ListView1.Align:= TAlignLayout.Client;
  for X := 1 to 50 do
    A;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  S: TListItemSwitch;
begin
  S:= AItem.Objects.FindObject('Switch') as TListItemSwitch;
  if S = nil then begin
    S:= TListItemSwitch.Create(AItem);
    S.Name:= 'Switch';
    S.Align:= TListItemAlign.Trailing;
    S.VertAlign:= TListItemAlign.Center;
  end;
end;

end.
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: The signature of TListItemDrawable.Render has changed in 10.1 Berlin, but it doesn't seem to affect the functionality. With Dalija Prasnikar's change (below) implemented, it works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is error in your `MouseDown` method. It should look like this:

```
function TListItemSwitch.MouseDown(const Button: TMouseButton;
  const Shift: TShiftState; const MousePos: TPointF): Boolean;
begin
  Result := inherited;
  if Result then begin
    DoSwitch;
  end;
end;
```

When user clicks on `ListItem` it iterates through all its visible subcontrols calling their `MouseDown` methods to see which one is pressed. If `MouseDown` method returns `true` that means particular subcontrol is pressed. In your case that logic is implemented in `TListItemSimpleControl` from which you inherit.

You were doing `DoSwitch` logic for all `MouseDown` events even when mouse was not pressed inside your control bounds.