# Something like DBCtrlGrid in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I have a TLayout that contains some controls like Image and Label, I want to show a list that has this layout as Items. values of Images or Labels should be retrieved from a DataSet

In VCL Library there is a control named DBCtrlGrid, I want something like this in FireMonkey, there is a control named Grid but I don`t know hoe to use it, I can add this Layout as list item on a ScrollBox but I want a control that can create the list automatically. DBCtrlGrid is exactly what I want

Is it possible to create this link by using LiveBinding between DataSet and TGrid ? How ?

I`m using Delphi XE 6 and my project is a FireMonkey Desktop Application

Comment: I cannot speak for XE6, thus only a comment here: TListView with ItemAppearance set to DynamicAppearance should do such thing.

Comment: Thanks, but how to add a TLayout or TFrame as ListViewItem ? there is only some Object Types like TListItemImage and TListItemText or ... .

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339179/create-a-customized-item-appearance-for-listview-delphi-xe7